# JSON Schema Validation not validating after one object in a JSON array -> Mule 4

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, mule4, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate a json body against a JSON schema and it is not validating after finding a data-type error in the first object in Mule4 Validation Module.

Please let me know if someone has any inputs TIA
Input ->

```
[
  {"a": 112, "b": "123"},
  {"a": 123, "b": ""}
]
```

Schema->

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "a": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1,
        "maxLength": 255
        },
      "b": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1,
        "maxLength": 255
      }
    },
    "required": ["a", "b"]
  }
}
```

Error->

```
[ {

  "level" : "error",

  "schema" : {

    "loadingURI" : "file:/C:/Users/Harshitkawdia/Softwares/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.4.4.0.ee_7.11.0.202303211414/mule/apps/schema-poc/schema/schema.json#",

    "pointer" : "/items/properties/a"

  },

  "instance" : {

    "pointer" : "/0/a"

  },

  "domain" : "validation",

  "keyword" : "type",

  "message" : "instance type (integer) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: [\"string\"])",

  "found" : "integer",

  "expected" : [ "string" ]

} ]
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your question? It is unclear what you need help with. 
"a" and "b" are expected to be strings in the schema and they are integers in the data so that is an error.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to be noticed here

1. Datatype of field a which gives a data type validation error since expected value is integer but it is validated for string
2. For field b , you have passed empty string but in validation you have provided minLength as 1 which ideally should not work. Ideally you need to pass minLength as 0

For point 1, either you can try with `anyOf` and validate that it can be string or integer

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "a": {
                 "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "pattern": "[1-9]"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                ]
        },
      "b": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 255
      }
    },
    "required": ["a", "b"]
  }
}
```

or you can restrict validation to integer only

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "a": {
        "type": "integer"
        },
      "b": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 255
      }
    },
    "required": ["a", "b"]
  }
}
```

Test cases

```
[
  {"a": "112123", "b": "123"},
  {"a": 123, "b": ""}
]  #Will Work

[
  {"a": "A", "b": "123"},
  {"a": 123, "b": ""}
] #Wont Work Since "a" : "A" fails the pattern match
```